# IntelliJ IDEA gives “The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK” error even it is a valid JDK

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to set a JDK path and IntelliJ gives this error:

`The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK`

But I am sure that it is absolutely valid because I can use the java compiler.

`javac Main.java` compiles the file correctly.

I am sure that the path is also correct because the command below gives me that path.

`/usr/libexec/java_home` prints the path below:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home`

When I choose this path on IntelliJ, it shows the error. I reinstalled the JDK and also tried to choose `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/` but none of them worked.

Please do not consider this question is a duplicate because I tried all of the solutions offered in other answers.

Comment: You tried to set the middle choice as your JDK home? (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home)

Comment: yes, actually I tried both but none of them worked. It is supposed to be "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home".

Comment: Can you post a screen shot that shows as much of the issue as possible?

Comment: I just installed JDK 10.0.1 on my Mac, selected it with IDEA 2018.1, and it worked just fine. My JDK path is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home`. I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the latest version of Intellij community edition, check their release notes here : https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+2018.1+181.5540.7+Release+Notes

Seems there's a bug "Manually provided JDK 10 not accepted in JShell: "JDK version is 8"

Hope it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: yes, it was a bug. I had to install a new version and works fine now. thank you.

Comment: @amone just for clarification, can you point out what have you upgrade, was it IntelliJ or jdk? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, but - in my case and I'm pretty confident in your case too - it is not related to the bug presented in the accepted answer. For some reason, IDEA IntelliJ doesn't accept any OpenJDKs. I tried all version from 7 to 9. It worked immediately once I installed the **Oracle** JDK (version 10 this time).

Also, you might have multiple JDK installed and when running the java command in the terminal - without knowing - you may be actually using a different JDK than the one you think you're using.

Use `which java` and then `ls -l` the resulted path to see what's behind the symlink.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your version of IntelliJ is newer then the JDK! (or better go to the newest version of IntelliJ)

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to set the jdk path folder and not to the bin itself in Intellij. I dont know if that is what you're asking.

Comment: Gosh, that is weird! That middle one should nail it.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of tool.jar and/or rt.jar file(s) being missed from JAVA_HOME/lib directory.

Reinstalling java can resolve this issue.

Comment: Reistalling the same version can't help because there is a bug.